# Office JavaScript API and Power point

Tags: api, powerpoint, office-js, sharepoint-online

I have embedded a PowerPoint document from a SharePoint online document library in my html page using an iframe. Is it possible to find the current and last slide of the document using Office JavaScript API.

Answer (score 0):

The PowerPoint document would have to have an Office Add-in installed to use the Office JavaScript API. There is an API, that will get the title, ID, and index of the currently selected slide (or slides): You pass `Office.CoercionType.SlideRange` to the `getSelectedData` method.

There's no way to get this information about the last slide (unless it is currently selected).